# Formulas within a macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I'm a total beginner in terms of coding i just took a semester course in excel so I apologize for being this broken
I'm trying to make a button macro that when pressed takes the typed out ID from a certain cell, copies it to a running master list on a different sheet, and then references a table on through index match on a different sheet and use that to insert a specific date (anniversary of hire +1 or +2 years based on how many days off they have remaining). Hopefully you can get an idea of my intentions from my elementary code starting with setting variables

```
    Private Sub Submitsp3_Click()
 Dim a As Long
 Dim b As Integer
 Dim c As Integer
 a = Range("M8").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Employee_List[[#All],[Days Since Hire]],MATCH(R[0]C[-9],Employee_List[[#All],[ID '#]],0))"
 b = Range("M8").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Employee_List[[#All],[Days left]],MATCH(R0C0,Employee_List[[#All],[ID '#]],0))"
 Sheets("employee info").Select
```

then a bunch of conditions

```
If a < 90 Then
MsgBox ("This employee does not yet have access to paid days off")
ElseIf b = 0 Then
MsgBox ("This employee is out of paid off days")
Dim answer As Integer
answer = MsgBox("Do you want to Continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
ElseIf answer = vbNo Then
MsgBox "Macro Ending"
ElseIf answer = vbYes Then
'''bunch of copy and pasting things around'''
```

lastly the part to put in the correct date

```
Sheets("raw list of dates off").Range("D3").Select
     c = Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Employee_List[[#All],[Days left]],MATCH(R0C0,Employee_List[[#All],[ID '#]],0))"
If c < 6 Then
   ActiveCell.Formula = "=EDATE([@[Hire date]],12*INT(YEARFRAC([@[Hire date]],TODAY())+2))"
ElseIf c < 6 Then
   ActiveCell.Formula = "=EDATE([@[Hire date]],12*INT(YEARFRAC([@[Hire date]],TODAY())+1))"
End If
   Sheets("employee info").Select
    MsgBox ("Date added")
    End Sub
```

my question is, it does seem like I'm doing any of this correctly. The current issue is that it always pulls up the first message in the code. Then gives an error 1004 and then highlights the "Sheets("raw list of dates off").Range("D3").Select"

Comment: There is no description of the specific problem and/or error that your code is manifesting.  There is no Question in your Question.

Comment: it runs through the entire thing, it doesn't end if a condition is met. I updated the post.

Comment: "does it seem like I'm doing any of this correctly"
SO isn't really a code review site.  People are happy to help if you [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  

As for your error.  You can't select a cell on a sheet that isn't active.  So if you add the line ```Sheets("raw list of dates off").Activate``` before trying to Select the cell that error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Insert - Tables make them actual tables,

Data - Relationships - Relate the two tables on EmployeeID

Then just do a quick Start Year math-a-mebob

```
 =Years(Year(Today())-[@Start Year]
```

Delete pointless master sheet and just ignore that query name in my example, as it's not financial advice.
[image]